# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'longformer.longformer'; 'longformer' is not a package

Tags: python

```
conda create --name longformer python=3.7

conda activate longformer

conda install cudatoolkit=10.0

pip install git+https://github.com/allenai/longformer.git
```

```py
import torch

from longformer.longformer import Longformer, LongformerConfig
```

results the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'longformer.longformer'; 'longformer' is not a package
```

Any clue whats wrong?

Comment: Why `from longformer.longformer` rather than just `from longformer`? The error seems to suggest that `longformer` is a module which you are trying to treat as a package (a collection of modules).

Comment: @Keren Segal what worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it from the transformers package:

```
pip3 install transformers
```

In your code:

```
from transformers import LongformerModel

model = LongformerModel.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096', gradient_checkpointing=True)
print(model)
```